# How do I add classes to blocks?

Tags: blocks, 8, panels

I am using Drupal 8 Panels and it is working fine. The problem currently I have is, that I want to add classes to individual blocks on the panel layout page. Is there a way to add classes to blocks on panel pages?something like the Drupal 7 version of CSS properties on panel panes?

Comment: No, this feature isn't supported yet. Create a feature request in the issue, this isn't an question that can be answered here.

Comment: I have a module that does this, basically you have to alter the block settings form and attach the classes in theme preprocessor.(I don't use panels)

Comment: For blocks you have block_class module, https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class

For page manager theres is a feature request
https://www.drupal.org/node/2710169

Comment: A possible better solution is being worked on for panels: https://www.drupal.org/node/2296437

Answer (score 0):

For custom blocks it's pretty easy to add classes without any module. Simply add a text (plain) field - or whatever fit's your needs best, get the value in the block.html.twig (maybe use Twigs |clean_class filter) and add it to the classes.